# How to use WebUserControl multiple times on same web page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, webusercontrol

Work on Asp.net web page application.I have one user WebUserControl,it’s contain two textboxes and couple of javascript syntax,my control copy one text box information in another text box.Problem arise when I used my user control several times on same page .
After used several times my user control not working properly,How to solve this issue

My user control syntax:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="transferControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="testControl.transferControl" %>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function IsAccNumberValid(txtAccountNumber) {
            debugger;
            document.getElementById("<%= txtTo.ClientID %>").value = txtAccountNumber.value;
        }
</script>


<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFrom" onblur="Javascript:IsAccNumberValid(this);" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

My used page syntax:

```
<%@ Register src="transferControl.ascx" tagname="transferControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


    <uc1:transferControl ID="transferControl1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <uc1:transferControl ID="transferControl2" runat="server" />


</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Multiple copy of the same UserControl on the same WebPage also creates multiple copy of java script code on the web page. In your case, IsAccNumberValid() will be defined twice on your web page ans it will throw JavaScript error for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your User control code like this. Following code is replacing IsAccNumberValid() function with a direct Javascript statements. So there won't be any duplicate function definition.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="transferControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="testControl.transferControl" %>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFrom"  />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var txtFrom = document.getElementById("<%= txtFrom.ClientID %>");
        var txtTo = document.getElementById("<%= txtTo.ClientID %>");

        txtFrom.onblur = function () {
            txtTo.value = txtFrom.value;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Kiran Varsani,thanks for your reply.your syntax not working.Will you please check.

Comment: I have changed the order of the script tag and TextBoxes. This has fixed the problem. TextBoxes needed to be defined first as in this case page tries to run JavaScript function straight away. Please give this code a try.

Answer (score 0):

A gerneral solution is to use a unique key.

Gernerate a unique key in the code behinde (C#):

```
protected string uniqueKey;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.uniqueKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
}
```

Us the key for a javascript function name or a html element id to make it unique:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DisplayMessage_<%=uniqueKey %>() {
    var message = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").value;
    alert(message);
    return false;
}
</script>
<div id="myDiv_<%=uniqueKey %>">Test</div>
```

Check [link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-multiple-instances-of-same-UserControl-on-Page-with-JavaScript-in-ASPNet.aspx) for more details.